# MinionPro: Tabular Figures in Tables and Proportional Figures in text

Tags: tables, tabularx, siunitx, minionpro

I am using TexMaker and MinionPro and I would like to keep proportional both in figures and in the rest of the document. For figures, I use this configuration:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{MinionPro}      % Minion Pro
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,threeparttable}
\renewcommand{\TPTnoteSettings}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\TPTnoteLabel}[1]{#1}
\begin{tabular}{
  l
  c
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=2.0]
}
\toprule
 & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Name1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Name2} & \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
 & & {Factor1} & {Factor2} & {Factor1} & {Factor2} & {Total} \\
\midrule
Test 1 &    &   12 &  2 &   3 &    5  & 99 \\
Test 2 &    & 1234 & 234 & 334 & {---} & 99 \\
Test 3 & X1 &    2 &  82 &   2 &    2  &  8 \\
       & Y1 &    2 &  11 &   2 &    2  &  8 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[Note:] A long note that goes beyond the table width
  because we want to have many many words that
  mean as little as possible
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

It looks like this:
[image]

I would like it to look more like this:
[image]

Is it possible to set things up so tables and the whole document automatically use tabular numbers?

It would be an extremely huge help!

Comment: First you say that you "would like to keep proportional figures in text", but you end by saying you want "the whole document [to] automatically use tabular numbers". Please clarify what you actually want.

Comment: Hi Sverre. Thanks for your reply. Most important is the figures, but if it is possible to use in the whole document, I think that would be the optimal.

Comment: I still don't understand. You say in your comment "use in the whole document". Use what? Your edited question now says that you want tabular numerals in "the whole document" and proportional numerals in "the rest of the document". What does that mean?

Comment: In addition to what @Sverre asked, do you mean that you want *tabular* figures? Or do you mean that you want *lining* figures? Or both? Tabular figures are non-proportional. All numerals have the same width: a 9 takes the same horizontal space as a 1. Tabular figures can be lining or hanging. Proportional figures can be hanging or lining. Lining figures have their base on the base line. Their heights are all the same: a 4 is the same height as a 1. None hang below the line. Lining figures can be proportional or tabular. Hanging figures can be proportional or tabular.

Comment: I don't know what Minion provides - many fonts don't provide all the possibilities. But although you say 'tabular', your target image suggests 'proportional, lining'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want change the figures in document, do

```
\usepackage[lf]{MinionPro}
```

Otherwise, you have to use `\figureversion{lf,tab}` twice; once for the regular cells and plugged in `\sisetup`

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{MinionPro}      % Minion Pro
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begingroup
\figureversion{lf,tab}%
\sisetup{detect-all,text-rm=\figureversion{lf,tab}}%
\begin{tabular}{%
  l
  c
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=2.0]
}
\toprule
 & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Name1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Name2} & \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
 & & {Factor1} & {Factor2} & {Factor1} & {Factor2} & {Total} \\
\midrule
Test 1 &    &   12 &  2 &   3 &    5  & 99 \\
Test 2 &    & 1234 & 234 & 334 & {---} & 99 \\
Test 3 & X1 &    2 &  82 &   2 &    2  &  8 \\
       & Y1 &    2 &  11 &   2 &    2  &  8 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT1:** Here a simple document where you can see the available figures:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[%
  lf % or osf
]{MinionPro}

\begin{document}
\noindent\Large
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
  package option \verb|[lf]|
    & 0123456789 \\
  \verb|\figureversion{lf,prop}|
    & \figureversion{lf,prop}0123456789 \\
  \verb|\figureversion{lf,tab}|
    & \figureversion{lf,tab}0123456789 \\
  \verb|\figureversion{osf,prop}|
    & \figureversion{osf,prop}0123456789 \\
  \verb|\figureversion{osf,tab}|
    & \figureversion{osf,tab}0123456789 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It was the [lf] command I were missing. Will it use MinionPro numbers or modern numbers. I think they look different, am I right? Thank you so much!

Comment: @A.F. - I'm not sure if I understand your comment, see **EDIT1** in my answer, maybe that helps.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you so much. Can you recommend other great i.e. usepackage in preamble for MinionPro-package?